# C# DataGridView display Price + $ and Quantity

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've create a datagridview in C# with the basic Price and Quantity columns. However I would like the price column to be displayed as decimals and a dollar sign. I've search around online and tried setting the format style for that column to be "c" but it didn't appear to change the display of anything.

Lastly I would like the quantity column to be limited to only numbers. I tried to figure out a way to validate the input but was unclear how to properly do so. Hopefully someone can help. I've attached my file below. I know this may seem like a rather basic question but it's one Iv'e been struggling to find the answer to online, partly due to the fact I'm not sure where to implement some of the suggestions I've seen people make. I hope you guys can Help. I greatly appreciate it.

Here is the c# project solution if that helps. Nothing special going on here.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2471262/catalog.zip

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping currency values in a struct for that column?

```
struct Currency
{
    float val;
    public Currency(float v) { val = v; }
    public static implicit operator float(Currency c)
    { return c.val; }
    public static implicit operator Currency(float c)
    { return new Currency(c); }
    public override string ToString()
    { return val.ToString("c2"); }
}
```

It will be 100% interchangeable with a `float`. Just pass values into your `DataGridView` like:

```
dataGridView1[column, row].Value = new Currency(value);
```